# Migrating from Laravel 4.2 to 5.5 (Authentication / Password Mismatch Error)

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-upgrade

I am migrating a project from 4.2 to 5.5. I have reached 5.3, I have taken backups for every successful version update 5.0, 5.1, 5.2. The problem is, after my 5.2 update, my authentication as working well and I was able to login to the system. However, after the 5.3 update, I am not able to login. I have followed all steps from official documentation for upgrading.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide the code segment where the error occurs.

Comment: If you followed the steps from the documentation then it should have worked. Something must have gone wrong along the way. Can you explain exactly what you did to migrate your authentication controllers?

Comment: I followed this tutorial form: http://slashnode.com/definitive-laravel-4-to-laravel-5-migration-guide/ . It didn't cause any issue while upgrading from 4.2 - 5.0, 5.0 - 5.1 and 5.1 - 5.2

Comment: I updated from 5.0-5.1 and 5.1-5.2 using official docs